# Why do some LFR graphs created using networkx have nodes which are completely disconnected to nodes within the same community?

Tags: networkx

I am generating [LFR benchmark graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.4770) with different values for the parameters. The nodes in some communities are connected only to nodes in other communities. This seems very strange.

I would expect nodes in a given community to form a connected component. I'm not sure if this is because my parameters are incorrect or if this is indeed intentional and my concept of community is incorrect.

I haven't found any info that will help resolve this issue yet.

Here is an example of what I mean.

Code:

```
from networkx.generators.community import LFR_benchmark_graph
n = 500
tau1 = 3
tau2 = 1.5
mu = 0.3
G = LFR_benchmark_graph(
    n, tau1, tau2, mu, average_degree=3, min_community= 40, max_community = 100, seed=10
)
```

This generates 8 communities, each with some number of nodes:

```
Comm  0 :    54
Comm  1 :    62
Comm  2 :    59
Comm  3 :    65
Comm  4 :    80
Comm  5 :    56
Comm  6 :    55
Comm  7 :    69
```

Example of one of the communities with nodes that don't have edges to other nodes from the same community:

[image]

I tried multiple parameters- different number of nodes, tau1, tau2, mu, average_degree, etc, yet this problem persists. Not sure what I can do to fix it.

What I expect is that nodes within the community are connected to atleast one node within the same community as shown in this image:

[image]

This should hold true for all communities in the graph.

See [networkx LFR documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.LFR_benchmark_graph.html)

Any tips/pointers/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!